# iPhone 6s storage problem

Tags: ios, itunes, storage, iphone

I have a 16 GB iPhone 6s. Just 7 days ago I restored as new because my phone keeps taking up all my storage. When I restored, I had 4 GB available, 5 days went passed and I was forced to restore again because I had no space. I didn't even download a single thing.

3 days ago I restored as new, again. I had 3.9 GB available. Yesterday and this morning I had 1.32 GB available, now I have 600 MB available. This has been a problem since my iPhone 5c on iOS 7.

I've done numerous restoring from backups and as new. I haven't downloaded any apps and in storage usage settings, it doesn't add up to what is being used. I've called Apple and all they say is do a restore even though I've done it many times.

If I delete an app, my phone will take up the space within a day. It got so bad I couldn't send texts because my phone would "forget" them. iTunes says I have more storage than I actually do. I've used 3rd party cleaning software such as PhoneClean. It freed up some but not all.

Here is a picture of the Storage section on Preferences after a recent restore:

[image]

It looks ok now but available space will slowly go down after a couple of days.

Comment: Check the possible duplicate question, it suggests explanations and debugging for the problem. Anyway, it depends on installed apps and use. For instance, do you stream music / videos? Do you sync photos with iCloud Photo Library? It requires quite a detective job to determine what app may be eating up space.

Comment: Nope and nope. I import all my photos to my computer and delete them off my phone

Comment: Do you have any suspects? Does it happen with a freshly installed phone (ie, no third party apps)?

Comment: I have restores as new and downloaded apps from the app store. I only downloaded a few. Once I downloaded them I would still have about 2.3gb left after a couple days,  I'd suddenly have less than 1gb when I didn't even down load anything.

Comment: What apps do you use? Many apps create a huge cache after a short use, tumblr for instance.

Comment: I do have tumblr and it's a HUGE storage user, but it has a option to delete cache so it's not tumblr. I will add a picture of what apps use the most storage to my question

Comment: Of course I can't... here's my storage for my phone..https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B92o0HIZOVnQUDZyaUlRaEJSaHM

Comment: The storage adds up now but give it a couple days and it'll slowly go down